# Can async image download have timeout or do I need NSURLSession?

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, swift4

Can this image download technique use timeouts: [Why doesn't image load on main thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47965917/why-doesnt-image-load-on-main-thread)?

Or must I use NSURLSession instead if I want to use timeouts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the `timeoutintervalForResource` property. If you use `URLSession.shared`, the default timeout is 7 days. If you want to use a different timeout, you need to create your own session:

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
config.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60 // timeout, in seconds

// A 20 MB image from NASA
let url = URL(string: "https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/hs-2015-02-a-hires_jpg.jpg")!

let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    }

    // do something
}.resume()
```

Lower the timeout enough and you will see a timeout error. Note that `URLSessionConfiguration` has 2 timeouts: `timeoutIntervalForResource` and `timeoutIntervalForRequest`:

- [`...Resource`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1408153-timeoutintervalforresource) is the time to wait for whole network operation to finish (default is 7 days)
- [`...Request`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1408259-timeoutintervalforrequest) is the time to wait for next chunk of data to arrive (default is 60 seconds)

If your goal is to download something in *x* minutes, using `...Resource`. If your goal is "network must response within *x* seconds or it's down", use `...Request`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to use NSURLSession. The timeout properties are in URLSesssionConfiguration and you just need to create an instance of URLSession using your desired configuration.

So, rather than using `URLSession.shared` directly you would need to make your own instance of URLSession and start the `dataTask` from that instance.

You are probably interested in timeoutIntervalForResource, which I think defaults to 7 days.

Here is a relevant Swift fragment from the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428793/nsurlsession-how-to-increase-time-out-for-url-requests/23428960):

```
let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30.0
sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60.0
let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
```

Comment: Do you have a link to an example using it as an instance rather than shared?

Comment: There are several examples on SO and other sources showing Swift3/4 code for URL session with a non-standard configuration.  I copied one such example for you.  You should be able to work it out from here.